# Calculating time till next cronjob

Tags: php, date, cron

ok i am made code that download any file to server, but there is a problem, i will execute cronjob that will delete folder and then make new one with same name, but i want to give info to users when that cron will run, so that means that i need code that will auto-detect next time that script will get executed, i have cronjob script, but i need to modify index so time will be shown in format

> Time till nect cronjob: $time here

this is my code for cronjob

```
<?php
if (!is_dir('downloads')) {
    rmdir('downloads');
}

mkdir('downloads');
?>
```

Comment: What does your crontab entry look like?

Comment: I'm going to assume it runs every hour. If you do `60 - ((time() / 60) % 60)` you get the amount of minutes left untill the next cronjob. Does that help?

Comment: it will run every day at 00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments above, there must be cleaner ways to do it though.

```
$tonight = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day')).' 00:00:00');
$diff = ($tonight - time()) / 60; // Time difference in minutes

echo "Hours: ". floor($diff / 60)." Minutes: ". ($diff % 60);
```

EDIT:
this also works

```
$tonight = strtotime('midnight +1 day');
```

Comment: Next cleanup in: Hours: 15 Minutes: 1 that get's diff backward

Comment: @AlešKalan backward? I don't get what you mean. Ah do you mean that it users 'previous midnight' instead of 'next midnight'? I think you made an error copying my code, I tested it a couple of times, feeding different dates/times into strtotime.

Comment: i solved it :) i was timezone, server time now is 09:06am and here is 3:07pm

Comment: Lol, perfect time difference.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $now = new DateTime();
    $midnight = new DateTime('midnight +1 day');
    $timeToGo = $now->diff($midnight);
    echo $timeToGo->format('%h hours %i minutes and %s seconds to next execution');
?>
```

***UPDATE***: used *AmazingDreams* notation, it's sleeker... :-)

Comment: Call to undefined method DateTime::diff() in /home/u830572651/public_html/dl/index.php on line 11

Comment: DateTime::diff was implemented in 5.3.0 (http://cz1.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)